# Rust lifetime operator requirement

Tags: rust

Consider the following code: you would expect that the reference returned from the iterator must live as long as the iterator. But rust seems to want it the other way around. Why?

```rust
pub trait IterValue<I: Iterator<Item = Value>> {
    fn iter_value(&self) -> I;
}

impl<'a, 'cellref: 'a> IterValue<std::iter::Map<ndarray::iter::Iter<'cellref, f64, ndarray::Dim<[usize; 2]>>, fn(&'a f64) -> Value>> for ndarray::Array2<f64> {
    fn iter_value(&self) -> std::iter::Map<ndarray::iter::Iter<'cellref, f64, ndarray::Dim<[usize; 2]>>, fn(&'a f64) -> Value> {
        self.iter().map(|&n| Value::Number(n))
    }
}
```

Error:

```
the lifetime `'a` as defined here...does not necessarily outlive the lifetime `'cellref` as defined here
```

Comment: Can you paste the full error printed by `cargo check`? It'll have arrows showing what the various "here"s mean.

Comment: “Rust lifetime operator requirement” is an awful [question title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/388112/620615).

Comment: Don't use generics for return type specification; use [associated types](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/generics/assoc_items/types.html) instead. The user of your API can specify generics; but the type of the return value is specified by you, the API maintainer. That's what associated types are for; values specified by the API.

Comment: Not sure why all the downvotes: this seems like a fundamentally interesting and important question. **If a question requires unstable features, it is getting at an edge case / rough edge of rust, and is perceptive.**

Comment: @Test The downvotes are because this question is very incomplete. It misses a proper error message and it is not a MRE. Further, its question title is poorly chosen. Nobody will ever find it again in future, as it is very unspecific to your situation.

Answer (score 2):

Achieving this used to be quite hard. Luckily, Rust [`1.75.0`](https://releases.rs/docs/1.75.0/) introduced [return position impl trait in traits](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/3425-return-position-impl-trait-in-traits.html), making this problem a lot more approachable:

```rust
pub enum Value {
    Number(f64),
}

pub trait IterValue {
    fn iter_value(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = Value>;
}

impl IterValue for ndarray::Array2<f64> {
    fn iter_value(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = Value> {
        self.iter().cloned().map(Value::Number)
    }
}
```

---

Before Rust `1.75.0`, it is still doable, but a lot harder.

- Change the generic to an [associated type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/generics/assoc_items/types.html)
- Add the `'a` lifetime to the trait
- Avoid the closure by using `.cloned().map(Value::Number)` directly

```rust
pub enum Value {
    Number(f64),
}

pub trait IterValue<'a> {
    type I: Iterator<Item = Value>;
    fn iter_value(&'a self) -> Self::I;
}

impl<'a> IterValue<'a> for ndarray::Array2<f64> {
    type I = core::iter::Map<
        core::iter::Cloned<ndarray::iter::Iter<'a, f64, ndarray::Ix2>>,
        fn(f64) -> Value,
    >;

    fn iter_value(&'a self) -> Self::I {
        self.iter().cloned().map(Value::Number)
    }
}
```

---

> But rust seems to want it the other way around.

It's not actually.

If you posted/read the entire output of `cargo check`, you would see that the entire `does not necessarily outlive` message is just a note:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src\lib.rs:10:5
   |
10 | /     IterValue<
11 | |         std::iter::Map<
12 | |             ndarray::iter::Iter<'cellref, f64, ndarray::Dim<[usize; 2]>>,
13 | |             fn(&'a f64) -> Value,
14 | |         >,
15 | |     > for ndarray::Array2<f64>
   | |_____^ lifetime mismatch
   |
   = note: expected trait `FnOnce<(&'cellref f64,)>`
              found trait `FnOnce<(&'a f64,)>`
note: the lifetime `'a` as defined here...
  --> src\lib.rs:9:6
   |
9  | impl<'a, 'cellref: 'a>
   |      ^^
note: ...does not necessarily outlive the lifetime `'cellref` as defined here
  --> src\lib.rs:9:10
   |
9  | impl<'a, 'cellref: 'a>
   |          ^^^^^^^^
```

The real error message is `error[E0308]: mismatched types`, telling you that the compiler expects `'a` and `'cellref` to be identical, not derived from each other. If you specify `'a: 'cellref` **and** `'cellref: 'a`, it works (plus you need to add the lifetime to `&self`, that's an independent error):

```rust
pub enum Value {
    Number(f64),
}

pub trait IterValue<'a, I: Iterator<Item = Value>> {
    fn iter_value(&'a self) -> I;
}

impl<'a: 'cellref, 'cellref: 'a>
    IterValue<
        'a,
        std::iter::Map<
            ndarray::iter::Iter<'cellref, f64, ndarray::Dim<[usize; 2]>>,
            fn(&'a f64) -> Value,
        >,
    > for ndarray::Array2<f64>
{
    fn iter_value(
        &'a self,
    ) -> std::iter::Map<
        ndarray::iter::Iter<'cellref, f64, ndarray::Dim<[usize; 2]>>,
        fn(&'a f64) -> Value,
    > {
        self.iter().map(|&n| Value::Number(n))
    }
}
```

But then the two lifetimes become pointless and you could simply specify a single lifetime:

```rust
pub enum Value {
    Number(f64),
}

pub trait IterValue<'a, I: Iterator<Item = Value>> {
    fn iter_value(&'a self) -> I;
}

impl<'a>
    IterValue<
        'a,
        std::iter::Map<
            ndarray::iter::Iter<'a, f64, ndarray::Dim<[usize; 2]>>,
            fn(&'a f64) -> Value,
        >,
    > for ndarray::Array2<f64>
{
    fn iter_value(
        &'a self,
    ) -> std::iter::Map<ndarray::iter::Iter<'a, f64, ndarray::Dim<[usize; 2]>>, fn(&'a f64) -> Value>
    {
        self.iter().map(|&n| Value::Number(n))
    }
}
```

Comment: *"You won't ever be able to write out the return type of your function because it contains a closure"* is factually incorrect, a closure that doesn't capture it's environment, like the one in the question, coerces to a function pointer, wich you can very well name, also while not stable yet, [tait](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2515-type_alias_impl_trait.html) allows giving a name to arbitrary closures.

Comment: @cafce25 Good point. I removed that point. Btw, according to recent conversations I heard about TAIT on RTIC, it sounds like it is far away from being stabilized.

Comment: Why can't you return `Box<impl ...>` instead of `Box<...>`?

Comment: @Test What exactly are you referring to? Where do I mention `Box` in my answer?